# SharePoint Documents

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365

In SharePoint 2010, there is a way to filter out documents from the all site contents site view.

`viewlsts.aspx?BaseType=1`

Is there a good way to show only document libraries in SharePoint 2013/ SharePoint Online (O365)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the requirement of showing a list of document libraries in sharepoint online , at this time, it seems there isn't any straightforward way to achieve the goal .As a workaround, you may achieve the goal by manually gathering the document libraries' links in a Link list or manually add all of these document libraries on the left quick launch of the site.

Please refer to [this thread](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/158/t/190628) .